# Testing local rails application with OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm building a simple dashboard app with Google Analytics API, which requires authentication through OAuth.

Can someone help me understand how I can set up a local testing environment so that the local environment works with the callbacks I've registered with my app?

I'm trying to avoid having to deploy to test changes.

Thanks!

Comment: user lvh.me:3000 instead of localhost:3000

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you know if there's any significance to "lvh.me"?

Comment: someone just got it and made it point to 127.0.0.1 aka localhost but because its a real domain name it works for OAuth and sub-domaining